# C switch case with function

Tags: c, function, switch-statement

can someone explain me this code?
I cant understand why printed value is 8 in this code

can someone explain it to me

```
#include <stdio.h>


int f(int i){
    switch (i){
        case 0 :
            return 0;
        case 1:

        case 2:
            return 1;
        default:

            return f(i-2)+f(i-1);
    }
}


void main(void) {

printf("%d", f(6));

}
```

Comment: Consider what is `printf("%d", f(3));`, then consider `printf("%d", f(4));` ...  Tis a good exercise to step through yourself.

Comment: Play computer with pencil and paper. Trace each step and local function values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you just need to step through the code in a debug run, but this is why you have `f(6)=8`

```
step1: f(6)
step2: f(6-2)              +f(6-1)
step3: f(4-2)+f(4-1)       +f(5-2)       +f(5-1)
step4: f(2)  +f(3-2)+f(3-1)+f(3-2)+f(3-1)+f(4-2)+f(4-1)
step5: 1     +1     +1     +1     +1     +1     +f(3-2)+f(3-1)
step6: 1     +1     +1     +1     +1     +1     +1     +1
final: 8
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a recursive function to implement the [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)

Lets consider a simpler scenario (in order to shorten response length) of if we were to call the function with argument of 4 : **f(4)**

Stepping through it we find:

- Called f(4)
- Hit default case statement to call f(2) + f(3)

  - The f(2) call will hit the case statement for 2 and return 1
  - The f(3) call will hit the default case statement and call f(1) + f(2)

    - Both f(1) and f(2) will hit their respective case statements and return 1
  - We now know the f(3) call returns f(1) + f(2) = 1 + 1 = 2
- We now know the f(4) call returns f(2) + f(3) = 1 + 2 = **3**

I would recommend the same process to see why a call of f(5) would return 5. And then using the fact that f(4) = 3 and f(5) = 5, you can understand why f(6) = f(4) + f(5) = 8.

Answer (score 1):

This is a recursive implementation the [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number), where each number is the sum of the two preceding numbers.

The switch statement works as follows:

- If `i` is 0, return 0
- If `i` is 1 or 2, return 1
- Otherwise, return the sum of `f(i-2)` and `f(i-1)` - this eventually boils down to the two base cases above.

Answer (score 1):

This is a recursive function which contains a switch case. Generally, in a Switch case, you need a statement breaker like **break** or **return** so that only that specific case executes correctly. Since in your code `case 1` and `case 2` return to same value ie 1 your code breaks down as a sum of 8 1s and final sum is 8.